# Trying to move 7.5GB folder from users D: drive to mapped network drive

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share, windows-10, mappeddrive

So, I've got this user trying to move a very large folder, about 7.5GB, from a 1TB storage drive in his machine over to a mapped network drive we have on a file storage server on our domain. I've checked his permissions, given him full control on the folder in question, he has permissions on the network drive and can move other folders to and from the network drive. Is there a size limit on files you can move over a network? The error that comes up says that he needs permission to move the folder but as far as I can tell he has every permission he needs.

If it matters the network drive is formatted to GPT and I'd be willing to bet that his D: drive is MBR.

Any ideas?

Comment: Paste the exact error message. Did the user try with smaller files too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, some files on the source directory has strange/too long names and Windows Explorer has troubles moving it.

Try using `robocopy` from the command prompt.